# How to Calculate the multi scale approximate entropy for a financial time series

Tags: entropy

I want to calculate the multiscale approximate entropy for the financial time series. The code which I got to calculate approximate entropy is as follows:

approx_entropy(ts, edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(ts), elag = 1)

But, I need to calculate multiscale approximate entropy which is not available in the particular package.

Comment: What is "multiscale approximate entropy"? some link, definition?

Comment: A multiscale approximate entropy helps to provide a quantitative estimation of randomness of the time series. Here is the paper link which used multiscale approximate entropy in their study.                                                https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1057521911001013. Kindly help me to compute multiscale approximate entropy in R. Thanks in advance.